# Android-How To Make the Text display

Tags: android

I am new To android.I have Some Code..I have

Simple.java :

```
 public class Simple extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      Button show;
      TextView view;
    EditText edit;

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
      view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.view);
      edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);


show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){

    show();

    }
});

}

public void show(){
    String text=edit.getText().toString();
    view.setText(text);
    Intent t=new Intent(this,Show.class);
    startActivity(t);

}
```

}

When i tried To Display the text in the same activity it works...
I am trying to pass the text Which i typed in EditText and to display it to Show.class

the code  for Show.class

public class Show extends Activity {

```
private Simple simple;
TextView text1;
Button back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
    back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.then);

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            start();
        }
    });
}
public void start(){
        String t=simple.edit.getText().toString();
        text1.setText(t);

    Intent t=new Intent(this,Simple.class);
    startActivity(t);
}
```

}

I tried this one I am not able to Display the text which i gave in editText in Simple.java.
I know it is basic but I do know. So Please Help me out.Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to show():

```
Intent t = new Intent(this, Simple.class);
t.putExtra("editText", text);
startActivity(t);
```

Then in your Show class' start() method, use:

```
Intent t = getIntent();
Bundle data = t.getExtras();
text1.setText(data.getString("editText"));
```

I have not tested this (and am slightly confused by your implementation...) but the putExtra and getExtra functions are what you will likely wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Intents extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText edit;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(activity2);
        edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        Button show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show);
        show.setOnClickListener(activity3);

    }
    private OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intents.this, 
                    startactivity1.class));

        }
    };
    private OnClickListener activity2 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intents.this, 
                    startactivity2.class));        
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener activity3 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text=edit.getText().toString();
            Intent t = new Intent(Intents.this, startactivity3.class);
            t.putExtra("editText", text);
            startActivity(t);

            //startActivity(new Intent(Intents.this, 
                  //  startactivity3.class));        
        }
    };
}





public class startactivity3 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actv3);
     //   Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.vi);
        Intent t = getIntent();
        Bundle data = t.getExtras();
        text1.setText(data.getString("editText"));

    }   

}
```

**Don't forget to add your new activity in android manifest file. go to your current application file click Application and add your new activity in my case i will add showactivity3 in your case you have to activity Show in your manifest. Try this code its tested**